# Finding Mode of Numbers in Array With Reduce and Filter JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this function:

```
const mode = arr =>
  arr.reduce(
    (a,b,i,arr) => (arr.filter(c=> c === a).length >= arr.filter(c => c === b).length) ? a : b,  
    null
  )

console.log(mode([500, 450, 400, 400, 375, 350, 325, 300])) // 400
```

I can see that the reduce function takes in two parameters, a function for the first, and null for the second.
The first parameter function returns what looks like should result in a ternary conditional checking if the left array
returned is greater than or equal to the returned array on the right.

I am still not exactly clear what is really going on under the hood, and was hoping someone could break this down a bit further,
in an easily explainable manner. It seems to work if the there is only one number that is the mode in the array, which is is fine for now, I can solve that issue later.

[Here](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/NvBQaR?editors=0012) is a working codepen to test it out.

Comment: The second parameter is the initial value. [See this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: is it more a question what reduce is doing or whta your callback is doing?

Comment: @NinaScholz I understood most of it, but nimrods answer, albeit looking quite simple, really did help me visualize what was going on better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduce function takes two elements from the array, and apply the function to them. Then it applies it to the result and the next element, and so on for all elements of `arr`.

The function compares the number of appearances of 'a' and 'b' in the array and return the one that appeared the most of the two.

The number of appearances are computed by `filter(c => c === a)` which means - return an array with only the elements that are equal to `a`.

This way, in the end, you'll end up with the value that appears most times in the array.

In the example you've given, the following happens:

1. #of 500s vs #of 450s ==> yields 500 (because of `>=`)
2. #of 500s vs #of 400s ==> yields 400 (400 appears twice)
3. #of 400s vs #of 400s ==> yields 400
4. #of 400s vs #of 375s ==> yields 400
5. #of 400s vs #of 350s ==> yields 400
6. #of 400s vs #of 325s ==> yields 400
7. #of 400s vs #of 300s ==> yields 400

In the end, the last result is returned.

Comment: This is pretty good. It's actually all I really needed to help visualize it better.

Comment: As a side note, this isn't the most efficient way to do this. `filter` goes through the whole array every time, so you get O(N^2) runtime.

Comment: That's fine. I can refactor it, just needed a brief explanation to clear things up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is proper SO etiquette here? Your explanation did help, but the other answer posted here, was a little more in-depth, which was what I was more looking for. It's also a little bit better for people who might land upon this in the future. Any thoughts on this? Perhaps you could just include a few quick code examples taken from the question itself? Next time, I ask a question I will make sure it's known that some additional explanation is required.

Comment: Sure I can add a bit to make it simpler to understand.

Comment: Thanks. Don't mean to be a pain, but just looking out for the future JavaScripters on their quest for enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

The arr.filter calls pass a value and the result is an array with just that number. For all items in the original array this will result in an array with a single item, except for 400. 400 is twice in the array.

Whenever the length of array with the accumulator value is longer than the array with the current value, the accumulator is returned. The initial accumulator value is null, the comparison is between [] and [500] and 500 becomes the accumulator value.

Then the comparison will be between [500] and [450], the accumulator stays 500. Next up is 400, the comparison becomes [500] and [400, 400]. The current value wins and the accumulator becomes 400. Since there is no other value in the array that occurs more than twice, the reduce returns 400.

Comment: This is a very good explanation as well. Granted, nimrod's answer did help me figure it out, but it may not be the most suitable for people that might visit this in the future. This was more what I was looking for, with a broken down explanation with examples from the code itself. Not sure what is proper SO etiquette, seeing as in I have already accepted an answer.

Comment: I also don't know. It was fun to figure out and I am happy you found it to be a good explanation. I'm happy.

Comment: I will ask the person who answered it and will give this an upvote for now atleast. If he doesn't respond in a reasonable manner, a day or so, I can perhaps change the solution.